# Open 4d NetCDF subdatasets with GDAL in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy

I have NetCDF files containing subdatasets with 4 dimensions: time, height, latitude, longitude.

Here is an example of the output of GDAL GetSubDatasets():

```
('NETCDF:"Martinique_ALT22.nc":height', '[30x30x30] height (32-bit floating-point)'), 
('NETCDF:"Martinique_ALT22.nc":latitude', '[30x30] latitude (32-bit floating-point)'), 
('NETCDF:"Martinique_ALT22.nc":longitude', '[30x30] longitude (32-bit floating-point)'), 
('NETCDF:"Martinique_ALT22.nc":Water_Vapor_Concentration', '[2x30x30x30] Water_Vapor_Concentration (32-bit floating-point)')
```

When opening these subdatasets in Python with gdal.Open() and ReadAsArray(), the first two dimensions are overlapped and I get a 3 dimensions numpy array.

```
>>> band = gdal.Open(dataset.GetSubDatasets()[-1][0])
>>> array=band.ReadAsArray()
>>> print(array.shape)
(60, 30, 30)
```

I read [somewhere](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2758) that this is due to the GDAL raster format accepting only 3 dimensions: bands, rows, columns.

Is there a way to keep the first two dimensions separated and extract these subdatasets in 4-dimension numpy arrays?

Comment: Cant really check if this works without the actual file, hence just a comment: I think you can just do a reshape to get 4 dimensions again, i.e.:

array = band.ReadAsArray().reshape((2, 30, 30, 30), order = 'C')

you might have to change the order from C to either F or A (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), not sure about that.

Otherwise, I would definitely consider using the netCDF4 package (https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/), which can easily handle many dimensions.

Comment: I think xarray is going to handle this case much better.

Comment: @BertCoerver The reshape() method worked for me. Strangely enough, the order option had no impact on the output. I had not worked with NetCDF files in a while and forgot about the netCDF4 library: thanks for the reminder, I am totally getting back to this library. If you want to repost your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying a reshape to the "array" variable you can get back the original dimensions:

```
array = band.ReadAsArray().reshape((2, 30, 30, 30))
```

Just a side note, it might be interesting to look into the netcdf4 package (https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/) or the xarray package (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/). These can easily handle variables with many dimensions.